# Best way to edit a serialized hash of boolean values in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, serialization, hash, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a table column called "preferences." This is just a serialized hash of booleans, as the only preferences are whether the user wants email notifications for certain actions.

So it's be like

```
{
                  users: { role_granted: true  },

          owners_and_co: {  new_comment: true,
                               commited: true,
                              published: true,
                              submitted: true  },

                     co: {    submitted: true, 
                            deactivated: true,
                                deleted: true,
                           new_co_owner: true  },

    requirement_editors: {     commited: true,
                              deactived: true,
                                deleted: true  },

       resource_editors: {     commited: true,
                              deactived: true,
                                deleted: true,
                    associated_commited: true },

institutional_reviewers: {    submitted: true,
                            new_comment: true,
                      approved_rejected: true } 
}
```

I just want this as a list of checkboxes on my form but I'm not sure the cleanest way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Though I don't have the time to provide a full solution, I can point you in the right direction: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html. You'll need to loop over the preference groups, and use `to_s.humanize` on the key, then same for the preferences. The checkbox would be similar to `check_box_tag "preferences[#{group}][#{key}], val, val`, `key/val` being the preferences key/val "submitted: true". That's the easy part! Then you'd have to merge the two arrays in the backend, while converting posted params "true" to `true` else `false`, and updating the column.

Comment: You'd also want to validate the structure in some way so your app doesn't accept faulty or tampered data. To do that, you might instead iterate over the original hash, and only update if the key is found in the `params`.